# Django get data from html table for database

Tags: mysql, django

I need get data from  using django framework, and write to database. Row are added to the table using javascript. For example:

```
<table id="tbl" >
<thead >
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>        
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Sarlay</th>
        <th>P1</th>
        <th>P2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="scrollContent">
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="Add_Row()" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button> 
<script >
function Add_Row()
{
document.getElementById("scrolltable").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '    <tr><td><input class="form-control" name="inp" type="text" value=""/></td><td><input class="form-control" name="inp" type="text" value=""/></td><td><input class="form-control" name="inp" type="text" value=""/></td><td><input class="form-control" name="inp" type="text" value=""/></td><td><input class="form-control" name="inp" type="text" value=""/></td></tr>';
}
</script>
```

Who knows how to get the data from this table?

P.S. I tried to use the BeautifulSoup to solve this problem, but it did not help me.

Comment: In it's present form this is a lightening rod for close votes. Update the question to show what you have tried. BeautifulSoup wont work because you seem to be generating the page with javascripts.

Comment: That's not related to Django nor BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0):

You should not parse data from websites without owners permissions.

One way would be to use browser's "developer tools" or inspect source code of that page and find out from where js is populating those tables. If you are lucky, you might find source in some reasonable format (json or xml).